# How can I write this query in Linq to Entities extension method as a where clause?

Tags: linq-to-entities, extension-methods, where-clause

Given the following SQL statement:

```
Select * From Customers Where ID LIKE ('%160%')
```

if ID is an int field, how can I use a Linq to Entities extension method to do this?

For string fields, I can do something like this...

```
filterExpression = "ID.Contains(\"160\")";
IQueryable<Customer> c = context.Customers.Where(filterExpression);
```

When I try this, I get the error:

```
No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Int32'
```

I've been searching for an hour on how to get this to work with no luck.

Edit: Modifed to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test atm, but I'd try this;

```
var myExpression = x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.ID).Contains("160");
IQueryable<Customer> c = context.Customers.Where(myExpression);
```

Comment: Give me the error: No property or field 'SqlFunctions' exists in type 'Customer'

Comment: @Scottie Hm, seems it looks for `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions` in the wrong place. Could you please try the edit?

Comment: Since I ended up doing something very similar to what you've posted here using the StringConvert function, I'll mark yours as the correct answer.  Thanks!